# Handling page-specific JavaScript in PHP header files

Tags: php, javascript

When designing a website in PHP, you typically have a `header.php` file that you include in every page on the site. The `header.php` file would include the `<head>` tag (among other things). However, I often find that I need to put page-specific JavaScript within the `<head>` tag.

The way I've handled this in the past is by adding IF statements to my header to determine what pieces of JavaScript should be outputted (i.e. IF this is the *home* page, output the JavaScript needed for the *home* page, IF this is the *about* page, output the JavaScript needed for the *about* page, etc.).

This is probably a terrible way to do it. What is the standard practice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, first of all, `<script>` tags do not need to be located in the header. It's perfectly valid to put them anywhere in the HTML document.

But if you're determined to include them in the header, a simple solution is to declare a variable that the header should echo which contains your script tags. For example:

```
<?php
$scripts = "<script src='script.js' type='text/javascript'></script>";
include("header.php");
?>
```

And then your header.php script would like as follows:

```
<html>
<head>
<!-- header stuff goes here -->
<?php /*echo out scripts */ echo $scripts; ?>
</head>
<body>
<!-- part of body goes here -->
```

Comment: Huh. I guess I did know that `<script>` tags don't *need* to be placed in the header but for some reason I always felt compelled to put them there. I guess my life will get a lot simpler if I just insert the `script` tags directly after the `include('header.php')` statement...

Comment: With this new wisdom, I've decided to *not* put JavaScript in the `<head>` tag but rather at the end of each page (right before my `include('footer.php')` statement. This will allow me to keep page-specific JS on the page it pertains to. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are actually including header.php in every file, just define an array before you include header.php and add the extra scripts to that.  Then in header.php, have it check for that array and write out extra script tags if necessary:

mypage.php:

```
$extra_scripts = array('jquery.js','jquery-ui.js');
include('header.php');
// Rest of your code.
```

header.php:

```
if (is_array($extra_scripts)) {
   foreach( $extra_scripts as $script ) {
         // Render a script tag
   }
}
```

Comment: That's interesting. So I could keep the script in separate JavaScript files and then simply import them. I guess that's pretty obvious, huh. This is nice from a coding standpoint because syntax highlighting doesn't always work will in a mixed-code environment...

Answer (score 2):

If you use a templating engine like [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/), you can inherit a *base* template as opposed to including a header and a footer and modify the 'blocks' defined in that base.

For example purposes, your base template might include a content block and a header_javascript block like so

```
{% block header_javascript %}
<script src='/js/jquery.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
{% endblock %}
```

Then, in your child template, you can override this block, call `{{ parent() }}` and then add your additional, page-specific scripts.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not using a templating engine this time around, but I'm definitely looking at that option for future projects...

Answer (score 2):

I can see that your question has been answered very clearly. but I would like to add something.

Well, technically, it is valid to place you `script` tag anywhere in your document but it is better to place your script at the end of document, unless necessary. it will let visitor still see your html and javascript yet to be download, and BTW normally you don't need to run you script until `DOM` is ready.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I do it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"> 
<head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Page Description" />

    <!-- Includes header stuff, css, js, google analytics, etc.. -->
    <? include('header.php'); ?>

</head>
<body>
 ...
```

This allow me to avoid repetitive coding while adding flexibility to my pages.